# What word could I use to simplify referring to it?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'm trying to describe a power but I'm having trouble finding the right terminology to simplify what I am trying to get across. The basic idea is that the ability in question can create two points, one is an anchor point that only moves relative to what it is attached to, while the other is a point that is actively drawn to the anchor point (pulling along whatever it is attached to).

I'm trying to find a set of terms that can easily describe these two points. I've thought of calling the first point the Anchor, and I've looked into the opposite of anchor as well as words that mean "to be attracted to". Compound words are totally fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you're making up a game or a story or a conlang, be aware that English (and human language in general) did not evolve to describe anything you can imagine. Especially if you're imagining that "power" means something more than energy transferred per unit time.

Comment: In ballroom dance, they're called Lead and Follow.

Answer (score 1):

#### `Anchor` and `Hook` would give the right idea

I've read your question a few times and I interpret it like this. You are trying to describe a magical power, which will allow you to pull objects.

It involves you placing a magical "anchor" on one structure, e.g. a lamp-post, and a magical "hook" on another object, e.g. a bird. The bird would then be magically attracted towards the lamp-post.

Between the two points, there is no physical structure, e.g. elastic rope, but the magic causes the attraction to happen, as though there was.